# C# - Call method every 5 minutes of a video

Tags: c#, timer, video-capture

The code below is a portion of a third-party library from a facial recognition API.

```
    public bool pullFrame() {
    bool ret = csharp_haServicePINVOKE.HumanAnalysisService_pullFrame(swigCPtr);
    return ret;
      }
```

What I need is for it to pull a frame of the video only every 5 minutes. Meaning that the video will be running but it will only pull a frame at 5 minute intervals to analyze that frame. I have read up on async/await and I'm not sure where to put it in the code/if it's suitable. I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: you can just work with a timer. If the diff between timer and beginn is 5 min you take the frame?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PullFrame);
        timer.Interval = 300000; // 5 minutes in milliseconds
        timer.Enabled = true;

        Console.ReadKey(); // Prevents program from exiting.
    }

    public static void PullFrame(object source, ElapsedEventArgs evArgs)
    {
        // Do something every 5 mins.
    }
}
```

This creates a timer which will call the PullFrame function every 5 mins.